# moving picture box to right and left

Tags: c#

i have problem with key right 
it says ( propery or indexer ' control.right'cannot be assigned to -- it is read only.i dont know what should i do to fix it.
can you guys help me.im begginer.

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int objwidth;
    private const int objheight = 50;
    private int objX , objY; // position
    private int volX, volY; // speed
    //bool v = false;
    int speed = 5;
    bool goRight;
    bool goLeft;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void keyisdown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {
            goLeft = true;
            tenis.Left -= 20;
        }
        if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {
            goRight = true;
            tenis.Right -= 20;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Instead of `tenis.Right -= 20;` you should do `tenis.Le+t -= 20;`

Comment: Thank you .can you tell me why we cant use tenis.Right - = 20 instead of reversing left for right key?

Comment: actually, I think you mean tenis.Left += 20;

Comment: Would one expect the control to move to or change it size when Right was changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Right property is a calculated readonly property, but you can increment the Left property instead:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
{
     button1.Left -= 20;
}
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
{
     button1.Left += 20;
}
```